# How can I get a simple bixby Action to work with refresh?

Tags: refresh, bixby

I have this action it its model file HandlQuestionTimeOut.model.bxb :

```
action (HandleQuestionTimeOut) 
{
  type(Calculation)
  description (Handles Question Time Out.)

  collect 
  {
    input (message) 
    {
      type (core.Text)
      min (Required) max (One)
    }
  }

  output (core.Text)
}
```

This in HandleQuestionTimeOut.js

```
var console = require("console");

module.exports.function = function handleQuestionTimeOut (message) 
{
  console.log("handleQuestionTimeOut -> message: " + message);
  return message;
}
```

This in the quiz.endpoints.bxb inside the endpoints bracket:

```
action-endpoint (HandleQuestionTimeOut) 
{
  accepted-inputs (message)
  local-endpoint (HandleQuestionTimeOut.js)
}
```

I am trying to call that action with refresh like this:

```
input-view 
{
  match: Answer(this) 
  {
   to-input: UpdateQuiz(action)
  }


  refresh 
  {
    if(true)
    {
      spec 
      {
        delay-seconds (3) 
        with-request 
        { 
          intent 
          {
            goal {HandleQuestionTimeOut}
            value: core.Text(Timeout)
          }
        }
      }
    }         
  }
```

// code continues...

Can you please tell what am I doing wrong? I don't get that HandleQuestionTimeOut log in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify you questions?

Though I noticed something, based on my personal opinion:

1) correct module.exports.function -> module.export.function
2) In the refresh section I think you need to specify condition for 'true' or is it there for debugging purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I've just verified that this issue is fixed in 20B SDK release.

Please refer the [release notes](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/release-notes/sdk.20B) for details about other changes.